# Creating Matching bonus using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I create a networking system where

User A registers person 1 and person 2 in a week and he gets a matching bonus and then when person 1 registers another two people User A gets matching bonus from those two people.

How can I structure the database???

I'm finding it difficult to structure the database. Please can anyone help me?

This is a diagram showing what I'm actually talking about

[Diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmM1L.jpg)

[Diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sso8K.jpg)

Comment: did you try anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would assign any bonuses the moment a person get registered. The algorithm assigning the bonuses has to deal with the complexities, not the structure of the database.

Using an algorithm for this is also more flexible, because you can change, and test, the algorithm without changing the structure of the database.

A basic setup for the database could be:

Table **USERS**:

| UserID | Name | RegisteredByUserID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | person A | 0 |
| 2 | person 1 | 1 |
| 3 | person 2 | 1 |
| 4 | person X | 3 |
| 5 | person Y | 3 |

Table **BONUSES**:

| BonusID | RewardedToUserID | ForRegisteringUserID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2,500 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2,500 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 2,500 |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | 2,500 |

This is a very crude example. Basically when a new person is registered an algorithm sorts out which bonuses have to be given to which users and these bonuses are stored in a table.

The 'BONUSES' table can then be used to compute the total bonuses given to each user, and the total of bonuses given out for registering an user.